# How many function calls per second?

Tags: java, function, call

I am writing a java app that operates on data generated in real time.

The data is series of floats generated at about 30 floats per second, I'm searching for a particular pattern in the data and want to find and react to it in the least possible time.

That said I cannot keep the process waiting for some data to buffer instead I operate on the accumulated series as soon as a new float is received (comparing it with previous ones)

Analysing the series each time leads to about 5-6 java function calls.

Now with data rate of 30 samples per second the program is running at 180 function calls per second!

Is this rate inefficient? can it lead to stack overflow after sometime or is it safe for modern hardware? what other tactics can be used if this is a very high rate

Comment: Stack overflow only happens if you keep stacking the methods (*hence the name*), what means you'd have to call the functions recursively to achieve that.

Comment: More interesting than the function calls is what the functions do. Most time will be spent there. Why don't you just make some performance measurements?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy  too many function calls on stack not returning fast enough could fill the stack up and cause overflow as well

Comment: As far as you are not spawning your operations in a Thread each seconds thats true otherwise not because it's sequential.

Answer (score 0):

In your JDK folder under bin you find an application called jvisualvm.exe that will enable you to monitor several things. You have general graphs for CPU/Heap/Classes and Threads. It also provides an state overview for Threads which maybe not that interesting for you. But the sampler may give a deeper look into the stack/heap if you find performance issues.

If you are running your operations on the main thread it may be an option for you to handle it in an own one.